# Add a space in a php string at an exact space

Tags: php, string

I have lots of date and time data which have been put together like so `05/12/2113:30`

What I want to do is separate into two strings like so `$date = '05/12/21'` and `$time = 13:30` so that I can prepare them for database entry in a correct format.

They are always the same first 8 digits (including 2 '/') are the date and the last 5 digits (including ':')  are the time.

How can i go about separating them correctly using php?

Thanks so much for your help and I am sure its easy I just seem to be having a brain fart moment.

Comment: Given that they're dates, you can also [parse them into a DateTime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and then [format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to your liking. That has the added benefit of being able to validate input right in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```php
$value = "05/12/2113:30";
var_dump(substr($value, 0, 8)); //05/12/21
var_dump(substr($value, 8, 5)); //13:30
```

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use substr:

- first substring will be date (from 0 to 8)
- second substring will be time (from 8 to the end of string)

```php
    $date = substr($str,0,8);
    $time = substr($str,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr) you can extract from any place.

```
$string = '05/12/2113:30';
$date   = substr($string, 0, 8); // 05/12/21  <-- from start
$time   = substr($string, -5);   // 13:30     <-- from end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin DateTime Object its actually quite easy when you can guarantee the input format.

```
$in = '05/12/2113:30';

$dt = (new DateTime())->CreateFromFormat('d/m/yG:i', $in);
echo 'database format = ' . $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

RESULT

```
datebase format = 2021-12-05 13:30:00
```